# How to get all values with the same key in a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary `mydict = {'Item1': {'name': 'pen', 'price': 2}, 'Item2': {'name': 'apple', 'price': 0.69}}`. How do I get all the values of the same key? For example, I want to get a list `[2, 0.69]` corresponding to the key `'price'`. What is the best way to do that without using a loop?

Comment: If price is defined for each element of mydict: `[mydict[k]['price'] for k in mydict ]` may work.

Comment: What does "without using a loop" mean? Without loop in python? without any loop in the background? ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it is possible *literally* without any loop, so here is a solution using list coprehension:

```py
mydict = {'Item1': {'name': 'pen', 'price': 2}, 'Item2': {'name': 'apple', 'price': 0.69}}
output = [v["price"] for v in mydict.values()]
print(output)
```

Or a solution using `map`:

```py
output = list(map(lambda v: v["price"], mydict.values()))
print(output)
```

All outputs:

```
[2, 0.69]
```

Comment: You could also use `list(map(operator.itemgetter('price'), mydict.values()))`